# Achieving non-linearity in a block cipher using only rotations, shifts, AND, OR, and XOR

Tags: arx

It is supposedly difficult to introduce enough non-linearity in block ciphers based on modular addition, data-independent bitwise rotations, and XOR to make them secure against certain kinds of cryptanalysis even though addition is used because it introduces non-linearity into the design that XOR does not have. But what if we also use bitwise AND, bitwise OR, and bitwise shifts (a left bitwise shift fills a fixed-length bit string with zeroes on its left-hand side)? And let's toss modular addition into the flames since that actually does not run in constant time on some processors.

I figure that bitwise AND and bitwise OR can be used to introduce more non-linearity than modular addition. Additionally, though I'm not familiar with the details rotational cryptanalysis, I figured that bitwise shifts can help to thwart it since the for some inputs, the outputs of a function using rotations might be made equal with a rotation applied to one of them. Bitwise shifts would not suffer from this problem. As an example, consider that for inputs $x_0 = 0101$ and $x_1 = 1010$ the function $f(x) = (x \ggg 1) \oplus x$ will return $111$ in both instances. But, if $f(x) = (x \gg 1) \oplus x$, then the outputs will be $0111$ and $1111$, respectively.

Comment: The circuit for an [adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) incorporates bitwise AND/OR and shifts.

Comment: @EllaRose I am aware of that, but I did away with addition.

Answer (score 4):

The brief answer is: Yes, you can!

You may wish to study [NORX](https://norx.io/), an AEAD scheme submitted to the [CAESAR](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html) competition, whose essential thesis is that you can simultaneously attain high security, high software performance, and high *hardware* performance by the same design principles as ARX, but replacing $a + b$, which is slow in hardware, by the approximation $a \oplus b \oplus (a \wedge b) \ll 1$.

Comment: "You may wish to study [GIMlI](http://eprint.iacr.org/2017/630.pdf), a permutation accepted at [CHES2017](https://ches.iacr.org/2017/), whose essential thesis is that you can simultaneously attain high security, high software performance, and high hardware performance by the same design principles as NORX, Ascon and Keccak, but replacing a+b, which is slow in hardware, by the approximation simliar to a⊕b⊕(a∧b)≪1." :D

Comment: I'd edit my answer to mention Gimli too, but I don't think I can do any better than you just did!

Comment: I do not know if I want to approximate addition.

Comment: @Melab The point of addition is to add non linearity. **The result does not matters**. The propagation of non linearity by addition and $a \oplus b \oplus (a \land b) \ll 1$ are equivalent.

Comment: @Biv That's fine. I'm just interested in trying it without addition.

Answer (score 1):

Notice applying xor against the constant 1 is the not gate. And adding either Or gates or And gates is sufficient to create any function.
Xoring, shift and rotation alone are not sufficient.